# how can 'const unsigned char *' be wrapped with swig for java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

How can the following C function be wrapped with SWIG?

```
int add_option(const unsigned char *data);
```

Currently I get this wrapped to:

```
public static int add_option(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char data);
```

Is it possible to wrap it for String, Byte[] or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     %module Example

     %{
       int func(const unsigned char *data);
      %}


      %include <arrays_java.i>

      %apply signed char[] { const unsigned char *data};


      int func(const unsigned char *data);
```

Use this code !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In the worst case, you could build your own typemap. But a %apply should be sufficient here. Try this:

```
    %apply signed char *INOUT { unsigned char *pSeqData };
```

[I adapted this from a similar problem in my *.i file, after months of not using Swig. YMMV.]

The %apply directive copies typemaps from one type to another. There's more about it [here in the SWIG manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn48).

Comment: Even if I add `%include "typemaps.i"` and the apply above, it is still wrapped to `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char data`.